# Trying to format the names of music files

Tags: bash, awk

tl;dr How do you rename a file /foo/bar to /foo/bar-foo for many different files in many different folders?

Right now, my mom's music is on a 32GB pen drive that she has plugged into her car. On the pen drive, there are folders titled by the names of artists, inside of these folders are folders labelled by the names of the albums and inside of these are the songs themselves. When my mom plays the music in her car, the car will only play the music from one folder at a time. She would prefer a shuffle play of all of the songs. My solution was to do

```
cp ./*/*/*/* /otherfolderonmycomputer
```

to get all of the song files into one folder, then delete everything on the pen drive, then copy that folder back onto it. There was, however, one problem. She has different versions of each song in different albums. These songs have the same titles as each other and the cp command wants to overwrite one or the other. The solution that I came up with was to rename the each of the music files as SongTitle-AlbumName so that cp won't want to overwrite anything and so that she can tell which version of each song she is listening to. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the stereo doesn't have that function, as in, have you checked the manual? It seems like a strange thing to leave out.

Comment: Yes, I am. Her car stereo doesn't have the best of UIs.

Answer (score 2):

It could of course be scripted (option #1), for which there are infinite possibilities; and 'awk' is one of many options (replace hardcoded "foo/bar/..." with (for example) `find * -name \*.mp3`):

```
$ for x in foo/bar/{abc,xyz}/{f1,f2,f3}.mp3
do
  newfile=$( echo $x | awk -F/  '{ print $3 "-" $2 "-" $NF }')
  echo mv $x foo/$newfile
done

mv foo/bar/abc/f1.mp3 foo/abc-bar-f1.mp3
mv foo/bar/abc/f2.mp3 foo/abc-bar-f2.mp3
mv foo/bar/abc/f3.mp3 foo/abc-bar-f3.mp3
mv foo/bar/xyz/f1.mp3 foo/xyz-bar-f1.mp3
mv foo/bar/xyz/f2.mp3 foo/xyz-bar-f2.mp3
mv foo/bar/xyz/f3.mp3 foo/xyz-bar-f3.mp3
```

But perhaps a nicer, simpler, more flexible (option #2) would to be use [pytagsfs](http://www.pytagsfs.org/Introduction), which creates a virtual (fuse) file system based on rules you define, which makes your directory structure "appear" however you want it to.  Once you do that, copy that virtual directory structure into a physical directory structure. That way, you can tweak the virtual layout, review it, and then just copy it to the pen drive "make is so", so to speak. (You may need a  rather spacious workspace for this, however.)

```
$ tree foo-orig  # or ls -R, whatever
... your files...
$ mkdir by-genre
$ pytagsfs -o format='/%g/%a - %t.%e' foo-orig by-genre
$ tree by-genre
... in different dir structure
$ cp -r by-genre foo-new  # make it so
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do you rename a file /foo/bar to /foo/bar-foo ?

```
mv /foo/bar /foo/bar-foo
```

to do it to multiple files / folders recursively using folder name look here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-recursively-rename-files-using-their-directory-name-pattern-367807/

Comment: I meant on a large scale for many different files in different folders.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

## Accept one dir with files as input argument.
die qq[Usage: perl $0 <dir>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

my $arg_dir = $ARGV[0];

find( \&wanted, $arg_dir );

sub wanted {

    ## Return if file is special.
    return unless -f; 

    ## Get last dir of current path.
    my ($album) = $File::Find::dir =~ m|/([^/]+)$|;

    ## Get extension of the file (supposed mp3 if music).
    my ($extension) = ($File::Find::name =~ m|.*\.([^.]+)$|);

    ## Remove the extension, because I will add the album name just before it.
    s/\.[^.]+$//;

    ## Rename each file into base dir passed as argument to the script.
    #rename( $File::Find::name, $arg_dir . qq[/] . $_ . qq[-] . $album . qq[.] . $extension ) || die;
    copy( $File::Find::name, $arg_dir . qq[/] . $_ . qq[-] . $album . qq[.] . $extension ) || die;
}
```

Run the script: Pass as argument the base path of all music files and the script will search throught the directory sub-tree searching each plain file moving and renaming it to the base path:

```
perl script.pl ~/temp/music/
```

Take into account last two instructions of the script, I have `copy(...)` uncommented and it will rename the new files without deleting the old ones. When sure that it works, comment that line and uncomment the previous one `rename(...)`. They are similar but copy obviously more secure.

Comment: I love the way you format and put comments in your scripts. Makes it so much enjoyable to read and follow. :)

Comment: @JaypalSingh: Thank you Jaypal. I try to facilitate the reading and understanding of the program to other users. I also like reading your answers and learn of your good skill using wonderful unix tools like `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Well a bit unorthodox but you can try something like this -

```
while IFS='$\n' read line ; do 
     mv $line $line$(sed 's#/#-#g' <<< $(dirname ${line#.})); 
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.mp3")
```

#### Test:

**Before:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -type f -name "*.mp3"
./c/c1/c.mp3
./c/c2/cc.mp3
```

**After running the script:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -type f -name "*.mp3*"
./c/c1/c.mp3-c-c1
./c/c2/cc.mp3-c-c2
```